# contentInset take only negative number

Tags: swift, view, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align vertically a text in a view.
For this, I call contentInset function, like this:

```
    override func alignCenterVertical() {
    let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
    let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
    let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
    contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: positiveTopOffset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

But this only work when the value "positiveTopOffset" is negative. (reverse that I want)

I want exactly this comportment but with "positiveTopOffset" positive, like in this part of code here.

When I let the code like this, with "positiveTopOffset" positive, nothing append. Why?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

I have to add `isScrollingEnable = true`, like this:

```swift
override func alignCenterVertical() {
    let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    isScrollingEnabled = true
    let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
    let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
    let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
    contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: positiveTopOffset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```